# SQL Server: execute Temp table inside dynamic query

Tags: sql-server, dynamicquery

I am working with temp table and dynamic query as well as. my requirement is in temp table I am inserting some unique value. After that from temp table I get unique key and implement inside where condition.

Here is code

Temp table:

```
Create Table #TempUniqueKeyTable
(
     ID BIGINT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
     ukey uniqueidentifier
)

INSERT INTO #TempUniqueKeyTable (ukey) 
    SELECT followedTo 
    FROM tblFollowers 
    WHERE FollowedBy = @uniqueKey

INSERT INTO #TempUniqueKeyTable (ukey) 
    SELECT connectionRequestTo 
    FROM tblConnection 
    WHERE connectRequestBY = @uniqueKey

INSERT INTO #TempUniqueKeyTable (ukey) 
    SELECT connectRequestBY 
    FROM tblConnection 
    WHERE connectionRequestTo = @uniqueKey
```

Dynamic query:

```
SET @QueryHeader = 'SELECT * from XYZ B'
SET @MainQuery = @QueryHeader
SET @MainQuery += ' WHERE B.uniquekey in (SELECT distinct ukey FROM #TempUniqueKeyTable  WHERE ukey='''+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@UniqueKey)+''')) '

EXEC (@MainQuery)
```

It's not working **in condition**. This part not returning any value

```
SELECT distinct ukey 
FROM #TempUniqueKeyTable  
WHERE ukey = ''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @UniqueKey) + ''')
```

When I run `PRINT` command it show generated query like

```
SELECT * 
FROM XYZ B 
WHERE B.uniquekey IN (SELECT DISTINCT ukey 
                      FROM #TempUniqueKeyTable  
                      WHERE ukey = '1EA8658C-F978-4DC7-9ABF-E4FF253A2284')
```

It should be like

```
SELECT * from XYZ B 
  WHERE B.uniquekey in ('A5B6BC01-5FEB-4554-90A7-4B5ADCC00D36','F75C6303-40EB-4119-A45A-D122E8118FA4')
```

Comment: You have to declare / create it inside your dynamic statement.  Just build your string into a single statement.

Comment: @scsimon so what will code, i havn't idea what to write. i tried lots of thing

Comment: No worries. I'm on my mobile but someone will have an answer in a minute I'm certain.

Comment: I think that the temp table can be accessed from within the dynamic query ([rextester demo](http://rextester.com/GEKQS44354)). So I guess the problem is with the syntax (an extra parenthesis) - can't be sure though without some sample data (including XYZ).

Comment: After your edit: what is happening when you copy-paste the **printed** command to a query window and execute it?

Comment: nothing happen because after in command it required uniquekey. check last line of question.

Comment: I see, no, you cannot do that with your approach; SQL does exactly what is supposed to do, the printed statement is correct. Do you know anything about cursors?

Comment: yes i know about cursors

Comment: You must build the `IN` clause piece-by-piece, iterating over the data in the temp table using a cursor (or alternatively a `while` loop). Do you know how to do this?

Comment: i haven't work that type. if you have share with me else i will search

Comment: I updated my answer, I hope it will help you solve your problem. It is a more-or-less standard technique. On the other hand, make sure you understand why your original approach did not produce a comma-separated list of values!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra right parenthesis:

`SET @MainQuery+= ' WHERE B.uniquekey in (SELECT distinct ukey FROM #TempUniqueKeyTable  WHERE ukey='''+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@UniqueKey)+''') '`

But I guess this is something you could have easily identified yourself. Perhaps I didn't understand the question?

**EDIT** 
You can use this approach to build your `IN` clause. Extra care should be taken to ensure that `@MainQuery` returns the correct results (i.e, nothing) when the temp table has no data.

```
declare @QueryHeader NVarchar(max);
declare @MainQuery NVarchar(max);


SET @QueryHeader='SELECT * from XYZ B'

if exists (select * from #TempUniqueKeyTable)
begin
    SET @MainQuery = @QueryHeader;
    declare @WhereClause nvarchar(max);
    set @WhereClause = ' WHERE B.uniquekey in (';

    declare @curr uniqueidentifier;
    select @curr = min(ukey) from #TempUniqueKeyTable;
    while @curr is not null
    begin
        set @WhereClause = @WhereClause + '''' + cast(@curr as nvarchar(40)) + ''',';
        select @curr = min(ukey) from #TempUniqueKeyTable where ukey > @curr;
    end

    set @WhereClause = left(@WhereClause, len(@WhereClause) - 1) + ')';

    set @MainQuery = @QueryHeader + @WhereClause;
end
else
-- make sure nothing is returned, for example:
begin
    set @MainQuery = @QueryHeader + ' WHERE 1 = 0'; 
end

EXEC (@MainQuery);
```

Comment: The `while` loop builds the `IN` clause step-by-step, until there are no more records in the temp table.